# xcodebuild ui test doesn't return output when the test fails

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, xcodebuild, xcode-ui-testing

i'm working on the new xcode ui test and i try to automaticate the tests. I use the command line xcodebuild to run my steps.

Here my command line:

```
xcodebuild clean test -workspace App.xcworkspace -scheme "App-Tests" -sdk iphonesimulator -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 6,OS=9.2'
```

Are there any possibility to return the steps where the test fails? I only receive a message that the test fails:

```
*** Test fails ***
```

full stacktrace:

```
2016-02-22 17:11:54.572 XCTRunner[5891:23654] Running tests...
2016-02-22 17:11:54.572 XCTRunner[5891:23654] Looking for test bundles in /Users/me/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B1A70A99-F4D8-4891-AE6D-41C322A2CE68/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/28B0EF2E-097C-4346-B571-B80478AEC77F/UITests-Runner.app/PlugIns
2016-02-22 17:11:54.573 XCTRunner[5891:23654] Found test bundle at /Users/me/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B1A70A99-F4D8-4891-AE6D-41C322A2CE68/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/28B0EF2E-097C-4346-B571-B80478AEC77F/UITests-Runner.app/PlugIns/UITests.xctest
2016-02-22 17:11:54.574 XCTRunner[5891:23654] Looking for configurations in /Users/me/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B1A70A99-F4D8-4891-AE6D-41C322A2CE68/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/28B0EF2E-097C-4346-B571-B80478AEC77F/UITests-Runner.app/PlugIns/UITests.xctest
2016-02-22 17:11:54.578 XCTRunner[5891:23654] Found configuration <XCTestConfiguration: 0x7fd3d2c15550>
                      testBundleURL:file:///Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-accc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/UITests-Runner.app/PlugIns/UITests.xctest/
                  productModuleName:UITests
                        testsToSkip:(null)
                         testsToRun:(null)
                 reportResultsToIDE:YES
                  sessionIdentifier:<__NSConcreteUUID 0x7fd3d2c140f0> E4F1F332-7E4B-4996-A6D5-D62E5635F874
         pathToXcodeReportingSocket:(null)
          disablePerformanceMetrics:no
    treatMissingBaselinesAsFailures:no
                    baselineFileURL:(null)
              targetApplicationPath:/Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-accc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/App.app
          targetApplicationBundleID:de.xxxxx
                   reportActivities:YES
           testsMustRunOnMainThread:YES
17:11:54.722 XCTRunner[5891:23662] _XCT_testBundleReadyWithProtocolVersion:minimumVersion: reply received
17:11:54.726 XCTRunner[5891:23662] _IDE_startExecutingTestPlanWithProtocolVersion:16
2016-02-22 17:11:55.067 XCTRunner[5891:23654] Continuing to run tests in the background with task ID 1
Test Suite 'All tests' started at 2016-02-22 17:11:55.671
Test Suite 'UITests.xctest' started at 2016-02-22 17:11:55.672
Test Suite 'UITests' started at 2016-02-22 17:11:55.672
2016-02-22 17:13:02.521 xcodebuild[5421:22725] [MT] IDETestOperationsObserverDebug: (ECEE4D2A-BEA9-4A4C-8E4B-596A499F5123) Beginning test session ECEE4D2A-BEA9-4A4C-8E4B-596A499F5123 with Xcode 7C68 on target <DVTiPhoneSimulator: 0x7fdbf9fa2db0> {
        SimDevice: SimDevice : iPhone 6 (B1A70A99-F4D8-4891-AE6D-41C322A2CE68) : state={ Booted } deviceType={ SimDeviceType : com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-6 } runtime={ SimRuntime : 9.2 (13C75) - com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-9-2 }
} (9.2 (13C75))
2016-02-22 17:13:04.266 XCTRunner[5898:24339] Running tests...
2016-02-22 17:13:04.267 XCTRunner[5898:24339] Looking for test bundles in /Users/me/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B1A70A99-F4D8-4891-AE6D-41C322A2CE68/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/7F3C246D-C626-498A-BAF2-238A05429403/UITests-Runner.app/PlugIns
2016-02-22 17:13:04.268 XCTRunner[5898:24339] Found test bundle at /Users/me/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B1A70A99-F4D8-4891-AE6D-41C322A2CE68/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/7F3C246D-C626-498A-BAF2-238A05429403/UITests-Runner.app/PlugIns/UITests.xctest
2016-02-22 17:13:04.268 XCTRunner[5898:24339] Looking for configurations in /Users/me/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B1A70A99-F4D8-4891-AE6D-41C322A2CE68/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/7F3C246D-C626-498A-BAF2-238A05429403/UITests-Runner.app/PlugIns/UITests.xctest
2016-02-22 17:13:04.272 XCTRunner[5898:24339] Found configuration <XCTestConfiguration: 0x7f7fc37132c0>
                      testBundleURL:file:///Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-acc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/UITests-Runner.app/PlugIns/UITests.xctest/
                  productModuleName:UITests
                        testsToSkip:UITests/test_App()
                         testsToRun:(null)
                 reportResultsToIDE:YES
                  sessionIdentifier:<__NSConcreteUUID 0x7f7fc37045e0> ECEE4D2A-BEA9-4A4C-8E4B-596A499F5123
         pathToXcodeReportingSocket:(null)
          disablePerformanceMetrics:no
    treatMissingBaselinesAsFailures:no
                    baselineFileURL:(null)
              targetApplicationPath:/Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-accccc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/App.app
          targetApplicationBundleID:de.xxxxxx
                   reportActivities:YES
           testsMustRunOnMainThread:YES
17:13:04.409 XCTRunner[5898:24343] _XCT_testBundleReadyWithProtocolVersion:minimumVersion: reply received
17:13:04.411 XCTRunner[5898:24341] _IDE_startExecutingTestPlanWithProtocolVersion:16
2016-02-22 17:13:04.752 XCTRunner[5898:24339] Continuing to run tests in the background with task ID 1
Test Suite 'Selected tests' started at 2016-02-22 17:13:05.370
Test Suite 'UITests.xctest' started at 2016-02-22 17:13:05.371
Test Suite 'UITests.xctest' passed at 2016-02-22 17:13:05.371.
     Executed 0 tests, with 0 failures (0 unexpected) in 0.000 (0.000) seconds
** TEST FAILED **
```

Thanks for helping.
Cheers

Comment: Can you provide more information?  I don't see a problem with your command line.  How far does the test get?  Do you see the simulator open up?

Comment: Yes the simulator open up. The tests run but by failing nothing on the console about the steps. It is not possible to track the position where the test fails.